# Android Why is this Animation not looping

Tags: android, loops, animation

```
 animation = new TranslateAnimation(lrobjkt.getX(),400,0,0);
animationback = new TranslateAnimation(400,lrobjkt.getX(),0,0);
 // set Animation for 5 sec
 animation.setDuration(6000);
 animationback.setDuration(7000);
 //for button stops in the new position.
 animation.setFillAfter(true);
 animationback.setFillAfter(true);
 lrobjkt.startAnimation(animation);

 animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){

   @Override
   public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation){}

   @Override
   public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation){}

   @Override
   public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation){

        animationback = new TranslateAnimation(400,lrobjkt.getX(),0,0);
       animationback.setDuration(7000);
       animationback.setFillAfter(true);
       lrobjkt.startAnimation(animationback);
   }
});

 animationback.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){

   @Override
   public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation){}

   @Override
   public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation){}

   @Override
   public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation){
     animation = new TranslateAnimation(lrobjkt.getX(),400,0,0);
     animation.setDuration(6000);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
       lrobjkt.startAnimation(animation);
   }
});
```

One Animation is running once and the other one twice than it stops, but it should do a loop. And my other question is how can i move lets say a text view from where it is to the max xDelta position of a device?

Comment: It is worth tagging with the language you are using to attract more views and answers

Answer (score 0):

Simply set a `repeatCount` on your `TranslateAnimation` when you initialize.

```
animation.setDuration(6000);
animation.setRepeatCount(100) // will repeat 100 times
animationback.setDuration(7000);
animationback.setRepeatCount(100); //will repeat 100 times
  //for button stops in the new position.
animation.setFillAfter(true);
animationback.setFillAfter(true);
```